# How can I build a good approximation of an unknown distribution when only having samples from it in order to draw from it in torch?

Tags: statistics, pytorch, distribution, sample, estimation

Say I just have random samples from the Distribution and no other data - e.g. a list of numbers - `[1,15,30,4,etc.]`. What's the best way to estimate the distribution to draw more samples from it in pytorch?

I am currently assuming that all samples come from a Normal distribution and just using the mean and std of the samples to build it and draw from it. The function, however, can be of any distribution.

```py
samples = torch.Tensor([1,2,3,4,3,2,2,1])
Normal(samples.mean(), samples.std()).sample()
```

Comment: This is way too broad a question.  What assumptions are involved?  You've given integer values, are you assuming the distribution is discrete (vs continuous)?  Is the support for the distribution bounded above or below, or is it infinite (geometric, Poisson, exponential, etc.)?  Have you tried looking at a histogram of the data you have, to see what shape it appears to have?  Is your sample large enough to be considered reasonably representative of the underlying distribution?  Decent distribution fitting in most cases either requires a massive sample size or making a variety of assumptions.

Comment: No assumptions whatsoever - I have no idea a priori. I clearly have the assumption of continuous variables with my Normal example - that's fine but really I don't know. Also I actually care about a multidimensional function but gave a simple 1d example as I can start from there.

Bounds let's assume I can get - if I can't I fake it by using the lower bound as the lowest seen in training set,  ditto for highest.

This is for acquistion in black box optimization. After a while I'll gather more examples, I just want to have the best approximation of the distribution at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

If you  have enough samples (and preferably sample dimension is higher than `1`), you could model the distribution using [Variational Autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Variational_autoencoder_(VAE)) or [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) (though I would stick with the first approach as it's simpler).

Basically, after correct implementation and training you would get deterministic decoder able to decode hidden code you would pass it (say vector of size `10` taken from normal distribution) into a value from your target distribution.

Note it might not be reliable at all though, it would be even harder if your samples are `1D` only.

Answer (score 0):

The *best way* depends on what you want to achieve. If you don't know the underlying distribution, you need to make assumptions about it and then fit a suitable distribution (that you know how to sample) to your samples. You may start with something simple like a Mixture of Gaussians (several normal distributions with different weightings).

Another way is to define a discrete distribution over the values you have. You will give each value the same probability, say p(x)=1/N. When you sample from it, you simply draw a random integer from [0,N) that points to one of your samples.

Comment: I like the discrete distribution approach but it doesn't work for me, as I want new samples.

I am doing sampling for acquistion in blackbox optimization.
So I have some samples, and I want to get new samples, test them, and pick the best ones for my next round of optimization.